# Заменил в проекте все compile на implementation, но предупреждение осталось!

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build, warning

Заменил абсолютно все **compile** на **implementation** в gradle по рекомендации (предупреждению) Android Studio, но предупреждение (warning) продолжает меня предупреждать:

> Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with
>   'implementation'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обновил

> com.google.gms:google-services **3.1.1**

на

> com.google.gms:google-services **3.2.0**

и все OK! Предупреждений больше нет!